# Is my domestic train component of a Rail&Sail ticket valid if I ignore the ferry?

Tags: uk, trains, legal, ferries, national-rail

An [Anytime Return London to Glasgow](http://www.brfares.com/#faredetail?orig=EUS&dest=GLC&grpo=1072&grpd=0433&tkt=SOR) costs £365.  The same route in [Off-Peak](http://www.brfares.com/#faredetail?orig=EUS&dest=GLC&grpo=1072&grpd=0433&tkt=SVR) costs £137.60.

An [Anytime Rail&Sail Return London to Belfast via Cairnyran](http://www.brfares.com/#faredetail?orig=EUS&dest=BFA&grpo=1072&grpd=M190&rte=989&ldn=1&tkt=SOR) costs £108.

Rail travel from London to Cairnyran takes one through Glasgow, among other places.

Is the train ticket to and from Glasgow valid if I don't take the ferry?

There's not a lot they can do; they *might* figure out that I never appeared for the ferry and blacklist me, but that would be after the fact.  The difference in price is very large and even the Anytime Rail&Sail is cheaper than the Off-Peak return, so for any train that can timetable-wise connect to or from a ferry, it should work.  Similar tickets exist via Liverpool or Holyhead to Belfast or Dublin.  The only additional restriction appears to be that the Rail&Sail ticket does not permit a break of journey, but that is a relatively minor restriction for most travellers.

(The advantage disappears for Advance travel.)

Answer (score 5):

In theory, [no](http://www.nationalrail.co.uk/1X):

> Break of journey is not permitted except to change trains

Finishing your journey short at least used to count as break of journey (not sure this is still the case any more, I think it's ambiguous since the transition from Conditions of Carriage to [Conditions of Travel](http://www.nationalrail.co.uk/Conditions%20of%20Travel%202016.pdf). Reading the section in question I certainly get very confused as to whether finishing short is supposed to count as a break of journey or not. I get the impression that MAYBE they wanted to cover starting late as BoJ but not finishing short, which would mean you could only use it in one direction).

Comment: I guess that they could in principle enforce it with ticket barriers (*you must pay an excess fare if you want to leave the station*).

Comment: @gerrit Indeed. The "In theory" part of my answer is quite important; in practice there's very little they could do. Bear in mind that using the station facilities (outside the gateline at Glasgow) (at least, in the old Conditions of Carriage; as stated, the new Conditions of Travel don't provide a clear definition) didn't count as Break of Journey. Nor did leaving the station to stay overnight when it's impossible to complete your journey in a day. So in reality there are few opportunities where they could catch you. The question though was "is this valid" not "can I get away with it"...

Comment: The restrictions on breaking journey are in section 16 of the CoT. Where a break of journey is explicitly prohibited (restriction 1X), the breaks allowed in 16.2, 16.3 and 16.4 do not apply. The excess fare levied by virtue of 16.5 would be the amount of the saving (that is, the total cost would be £365). Now, breaking the journey **at the ferry terminal** would be a lot harder to police, of course.

Comment: @AndrewLeach "The restrictions on breaking journey are in section 16 of the CoT." Source? The section is entitled "16. General conditions applying to Tickets", and there's nothing to suggest that the conditions are only valid when Break of Journey is allowed. Indeed, it specifically talks about Break of Journey specifically being prohibited, then goes on to talk about starting late and finishing short as if they were separate issues. Of course, I'm not a lawyer, and I wouldn't try starting late/finishing short on these non-BoJ tickets myself.

Comment: There are occasional news reports about UK train passengers being fined for getting off the train before reaching the ticketed destination. The most recent I can find is from May 2016: http://www.thenorthernecho.co.uk/news/14469113.Rail_passenger_treated__like_a_criminal__after_travelling_on_Newcastle_to_Leeds_ticket___but_getting_off_at_Darlington/

Comment: @Muzer Oh come on. "The Conditions in this section apply to ordinary train Tickets, but may vary for individual products, especially discount and promotional Tickets. Most tickets allow you to break your journey, ..." but Restriction 1X explicitly prohibits it. Thus 16.5 applies.

Comment: @AndrewLeach That second sentence you quoted is in an entirely different paragraph, though. If it had been written like you quoted just there I'd see your point. Again, I think I somewhat understand what the intention was (though I genuinely wonder if the wording of 16.4 was meant to imply you can always finish short? The fact that the previous sentence uses words like "Generally" and "as long as the Ticket you hold is valid" and the one allowing finishing short doesn't contain such wording), but I feel the new wording is REALLY ambiguous and unclear compared to the old wording.

Comment: All the paragraphs have to be read together. The fact that they are numbered does not prevent that. "Generally" indicates what happens generally, unless something specific supervenes (like Restriction 1X). Yes, you can always finish short, unless you are prevented from doing so by a Restriction or by taking a train for which your ticket is not valid (because the station is reached via a different route, or the ticket is subject to time restrictions, or whatever).

Comment: @AndrewLeach So is your opinion that finishing short counts as break of journey or not? I'm confused by your last statement there. For the record, I completely agree that break of journey is not valid at all, ever, with this ticket. If I ever indicated otherwise, I apologise. What I AM confused by is what nowadays counts as a break of journey, since the term is no longer explicitly defined anywhere.

Comment: Yes, finishing short does count as a break of journey -- the journey is broken, apparently to be resumed later. It may not be valid if, for  example, the journey would become a peak-time journey because it now ended before the off-peak threshold, or a ticket explicitly excluded it [as here], or if you needed to use a strange route to get to the short station because none of the trains on your direct route ever stopped there (that reason might be contrived, but it is conceivable).